Upload file along with JSON body
I'm trying to upload a file along with some credential information that I will save as JSON in the database. I'm using form data to send both the file and credentials. However, I need the credentials to be a dictionary with str type keys and Any type values. Here is the code written in FastAPI:
@router.post('/upload', response_model=SuccessResponse)
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...), credential: Dict[str, Any] = Form(...)):
     return response.success(SuccessResponse(data=credential))

Below is the cURL example I'm trying to use:
curl --location '127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/file/upload' \
--form 'file=@"/Users/hanie/Desktop/example.jpg"' \
--form 'credential[user_id]="2"' \
--form 'credential[page_id]="1"'

However, I keep encountering an error indicating that the credentials are missing:
{"detail": [
    {
        "type": "missing",
        "loc": [
            "body",
            "credential"
        ],
        "msg": "Field required",
        "input": null
    }
]}

I thought about adding a dependency to the credential field and parsing it with a function like this:
async def parse_dict_form(request: Request) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    form_data = await request.form()
    result = {}
    prefix_with_brackets = "credential["
    for key, value in form_data.items():
        if key.startswith(prefix_with_brackets) and key.endswith(']'):
            actual_key = key[len(prefix_with_brackets):-1]
            result[actual_key] = value
    return result

@router.post('/upload', response_model=SuccessResponse)
async def upload(
        file: UploadFile = File(...), 
        credential: Dict[str, Any] = Depends(parse_dict_form)
):
    return response.success(SuccessResponse(data=credential))

This solution works, but it causes issues with the documentation, as it doesn't correctly identify the credential field.
Documentation before adding the dependency:

Documentation after adding the dependency:

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

In addition to the suggestions in that answer, you can add documentation to fields manually: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/ - There's also information about how Pydantic uses JSON available here if that might be helpful: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/json_schema/ - and instead of parsing the fields manually, you can also allow a JSON object and then use model_validate_json to parse it into one of your models. I'm not sure if you can actually change the defined type of object in that response, so you might have to use a manually added example instead
